# Verify Stokes' Theorem for a hemisphere where the radius is not 1

Tags: vector-fields, spherical-coordinates, stokes-theorem

I am trying to verify Stokes' Theorem for a hemisphere with radius 3.  I have only worked and found examples where the unit sphere has been used and I'm not sure how to factor in the value of the radius.  **This is the full question I am trying to answer:**

Verify Stokes' Theorem for the hemisphere $D: x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 9, z\geq0$ its bounding circle $C: x^2 + y^2 = 9, z=0$ and the vector field $\overrightarrow{A} = y\overrightarrow{i} - x\overrightarrow{j}$.

(I'm sure this is a really stupid question so please forgive me, I'm really struggling and nothing I've read or watched has helped me get to the solution.)

Comment: $r=1$ for a "unit" hemisphere; for this hemisphere, $r=3$. (Or, if you're talking about a hemisphere of "radius $9$", then $r=9$, but then the hemisphere would have equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=81$.)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose for the moment that $C$ is the unit circle in the plane $z=0$ ($x^2+y^2=1$), and $D$ is the hemisphere with radius $1$ ($x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, $z\ge0$). We parameterize $C$ by

$$\vec r(t)=\cos t\,\vec\imath+\sin t\,\vec\jmath$$

with $0\le t\le2\pi$, and $D$ by

$$\vec s(u,v)=\cos u\sin v\,\vec\imath+\sin u\sin v\,\vec\jmath+\cos v\,\vec k$$

with $0\le u\le2\pi$ and $0\le v\le\pi$.

For the hemisphere with radius $3$ ($x^2+y^2+z^2=9$, $z\ge0$), we make the following adjustments:

$$\vec r(t)=\color{red}3\cos t\,\vec\imath+\color{red}3\sin t\,\vec\jmath$$

$$\vec s(u,v)=\color{red}3\cos u\sin v\,\vec\imath+\color{red}3\sin u\sin v\,\vec\jmath+\color{red}3\cos v\,\vec k$$